# Backbone.js - trouble using jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Im having some trouble with using jQuery.append() and backbonejs. As it is now, when it tries to append, nothing happends (except it returns the jQuery object [seen in immediate window]) count is still 0. Ive tried adding the element manually, with no success. Ive also tried to append using just string () and this for some reason works. The thought here is to load up some objects at pageload, and change its dependat selectbox based on the value selected in the first box. But I am as you can see, a bit stuck. (Which is annoying for such a trivial thing such as this). The source I've used as a guide is found here: https://github.com/shinetech/CascadingSelectsWithBackboneJS/blob/master/public/javascripts/application.js

```
$(function () {
    window.AgfaRis = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($("#agfaris-template").html()),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, "render");
        },

        render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.EstablishHospitals();
            return this; // MUST return this
        },

// RELEVANT STUFF FROM HERE ON
        EstablishHospitals: function() {
            var hospitals = new Hospitals();
            hospitals.url = "/_Systemer/AgfaRis/GetHospitals/" + this.model.attributes.Id;

            var hospitalsView = new HospitalsView({el: $("#Hospitals"), collection: hospitals});
            var hospitalRolesView = new HospitalRolesView({el: $("#HospitalRoles"), collection: new HospitalRoles()});

            hospitalsView.hospitalRolesView = hospitalRolesView;
            hospitals.fetch();
        }
    });


    var Hospital = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var HospitalRole = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var Hospitals = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Hospital });
    var HospitalRoles = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: HospitalRole });

    var LocationView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "option",

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, "render");
        },

        render: function() {
             $(this.el).attr('value', this.model.get('Id')).html(this.model.get('Name'));
             return this;
        }
    });

    var LocationsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            "change": "changeSelected"
        },

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        },

        addOne: function(location) {
            var locationView = new LocationView({ model: location });
            this.locationViews.push(locationView);
            $(this.el).append(locationView.render().el);
        },

        addAll: function() {
            _.each(this.locationViews, function(locationView) { locationView.remove(); });
            this.locationViews = [];
            this.collection.each(this.addOne);
            if(this.selectedId) {
                $(this.el).val(this.selectedId);
            }
        },

        changeSelected: function() {
            this.setSelectedId($(this.el).val());
        },

        populateFrom: function(url) {
            this.collection.url = url;
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.setDisabled(false);
        },

        setDisabled: function(disabled) {
            $(this.el).attr('disabled', disabled);
        }
    });

    var HospitalsView = LocationsView.extend({
        setSelectedId: function(hospitalId) {
            this.hospitalRolesView.selectedId = null;
            this.hospitalRolesView.setHospitalId(hospitalId);
        }
    });

    var HospitalRolesView = LocationsView.extend({
        setHospitalId: function(hospitalId) {
            this.populateFrom("/_Systemer/AgfaRis/GetHospitalRoles/" + hospitalId);
        }
    });
});
```

Debug data

```
this.model.get('Id') and .get('Name') works, they return the value and text seen below.

(HtmlOptionElement)
this.locationViews[0].render().el
{...}
    defaultSelected: false
    form: null
    index: 0
    label: ""
    selected: false
    text: "--- Velg Sykehus ---"
    value: "--- Velg Sykehus ---"
    dataFld: ""
    dataFormatAs: ""
    dataSrc: ""
    currentStyle: {...}
    runtimeStyle: {...}
    accessKey: ""
    className: ""
    contentEditable: "inherit"
    dir: ""
    disabled: false
    id: ""
    innerHTML: "--- Velg Sykehus ---"
    isContentEditable: false
    lang: ""
    offsetHeight: 0
    offsetLeft: 0
    offsetParent: null
    offsetTop: 0
    offsetWidth: 0
    onabort: null
    onblur: null
    oncanplay: null
    oncanplaythrough: null
    onchange: null
    onclick: null
    oncontextmenu: null
    ondblclick: null
    ondrag: null
    ondragend: null
    ondragenter: null
    ondragleave: null
    ondragover: null
    ondragstart: null
    ondrop: null
    ondurationchange: null
    onemptied: null
    onended: null
    onerror: null
    onfocus: null
    oninput: null
    onkeydown: null
    onkeypress: null
    onkeyup: null
    onload: null
    onloadeddata: null
    onloadedmetadata: null
    onloadstart: null
    onmousedown: null
    onmousemove: null
    onmouseout: null
    onmouseover: null
    onmouseup: null
    onmousewheel: null
    onpause: null
    onplay: null
    onplaying: null
    onprogress: null
    onratechange: null
    onreadystatechange: null
    onreset: null
    onscroll: null
    onseeked: null
    onseeking: null
    onselect: null
    onstalled: null
    onsubmit: null
    onsuspend: null
    ontimeupdate: null
    onvolumechange: null
    onwaiting: null
    outerHTML: "<option value="--- Velg Sykehus ---">--- Velg Sykehus ---</option>"
    style: {...}
    tabIndex: 0
    title: ""
    all: {...}
    behaviorUrns: {...}
    canHaveChildren: true
    canHaveHTML: true
    children: {...}
    document: {...}
    filters: {...}
    hideFocus: false
    innerText: "--- Velg Sykehus ---"
    isDisabled: false
    isMultiLine: true
    isTextEdit: false
    language: ""
    onactivate: null
    onafterupdate: null
    onbeforeactivate: null
    onbeforecopy: null
    onbeforecut: null
    onbeforedeactivate: null
    < More... (The first 100 of 259 items were displayed.) >


<select id="Hospitals">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select><br />
<select id="HospitalRoles">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As a side note, there are no errors and everything works (except for the append operation)

Answer (score 0):

yeah there will always be problems with appending the "OPTIONS" element to a SELECT element. If you remove the VIEW LocationView and do adding with this.el.options.add then you will have no probs...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp